# Angular 2 Property undefined while checking it

Tags: angular, types

got a very little problem.

```
if(this.arrTest[1][1][1][0][0] === undefined){
      console.log("this array is undefined");
}
```

Console: 
**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined**

I use the same type checking quite often in my project. Only on this line it fails, tried also if(arrTest..), if(typeof arrTest..). Any idea ?

EDIT: The console.log does not get triggered.

Comment: can you please add some more information? what is the context of this conditional block? a component? class? service? cant help you with that little info

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Found it out by my own. Thank you.  It had nothing to do with a component, class, or something else. I just did not read the error carefully enough, it already says that property 1 is undefined so I just cant check a deeper property ...

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the property that is being matched does not exist.

That would happen if one the following is true

- this.arrTest is undefined or
- this.arrTest[1] is undefined
- this.arrTest[1][1] is undefined.

So essentially  you could check for all the above as follows

```
if(this.arrTest === undefined || this.arrTest[1] === undefined || this.arrTest[1][1] === undefined || this.arrTest[1][1][1] === undefined || this.arrTest[1][1][1][0] === undefined || this.arrTest[1][1][1][0][0] === undefined )
```

Comment: I think for `this.arrTest[1][1][1][0][0]` if `this.arrTest[1][1]` is undefined then too the error message would be shown as `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`